# How can I import multiple images in React? I have object instead of path

Tags: reactjs, image, object, import

I'm trying to load images from component which i called "Images" in second component. I'am importing "Images" like "import Images from ./Images" and I recive an array of objects. In object I have some additional information and path. But path is not a text but an object.

I tried import directly one image in component (not from other file) and I got path. Why once I get path and once object?

My code for importing images from disc:

```
import img0 from "../images/promo/1.jpg";
import img1 from "../images/promo/2.jpg";
import img2 from "../images/promo/3.jpg";

const Images = [
  {
    id: 0,
    path: { img0 },
    description: "description 1",
    name: "photo1"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    path: { img1 },
    description: "description 2",
    name: "photo2"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path: { img2 },
    description: "description 3",
    name: "photo3"
  }
];

export default Images;
```

In other component I`m getting my images array

```
import Images from "../components/Images";
console.log(Images[0]);
```

I expect output:

```
{
  description: "description 1",
  id: 0,
  name: "photo1",
  path: "/static/media/1.jpg"
}
```

but output is:

```
{
  description: "description 1",
  id: 0,
  name: "photo1",
  path: {img0: "/static/media/1.jpg"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path: { img0 }` is the short hand notation for `path: { "img0": img0 }`. Thats why you get that.

Comment: You are right. I used to write "{}" because of React. Stupid mistake hehe. THANKS!